# Как закрыть все активности, кроме главной? Android

Tags: java, android

Как можно программно закрыть все активности, кроме главной?

Comment: возможно [поможет](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330260/finish-all-previous-activities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приверно так.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
ComponentName cn = intent.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
startActivity(mainIntent);
```